# How to see segment.io data in Google Analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am new to analytics and stuck at one point i.e Segment.io (customer data hub). I created an Android app integrated with the Segment Android SDK and expected to see segment.io data in Google Analytics. What is the process I have to follow to see the data of Segment in Google Analytics?

Answer (score 1):

The process is:

1. Install Segment Android SDK into your app (already done, as follows from your post)
2. Go to Google Analytics (Admin Panel) and create a new property with "Mobile App" type. GA will asign you a new counter id UA-XXXXXX-X
3. Go to Segment.IO "Integrations" and turn on Google Analytics. Paste Google analytics counter id UA-XXXXXX-X into "MOBILE TRACKING ID" field. Save changes.

Now, if your mobile app is calling screen and track methods of the Segment API SDK correctly (check Segment.IO's Debugger) - all events will be passed to Google Analytics and showed in Behavior-Events, and screens in Behavior-Screens sections.